# Javascript Regex (alphabet)\n(alphabet)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string in Javascript:

```
var value = "required when\nmembers of the\npublic. \nHowever another example"
```

Note `n\nm` and `e\np` in the example above.

I would like to replace instances like the above with a space so that it becomes `"required when members of the public. \nHowever another example"`.

My biggest challenge is to get my regex recognised.

```
if(value.match(/^[A-Za-z]\\n^[A-Za-z]/)){
      console.log("Yup a match has been found!");
}
```

I am not able to enter the if clause. Anyone recognised anything that should/shouldn't be there?

Comment: You are not matching spaces (which exist in the input), nor are you repeating the character set (your lines are composed of more than one character)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to CertainPerformance:

```
if(value.match(/^.*[A-Za-z]\n[A-Za-z].*/)){
      console.log("Yup a match has been found!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of two regex, first to get new line between alphabets characters, replace new line with space, now on the replace one find new line line and add space before it

```js
let value = "required when\nmembers of the\npublic. \nHowever another example"

let final = value.replace(/([a-z])\n([a-z])/gi,'$1 $2').replace(/\n/g,' $&')

console.log(final)
```